# React.FunctionComponent interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, children, react-functional-component

My question could be a bit primitive but still I did not get the answer.

Let's consider the below :

```
const Box: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

We know that this generic automatically defines children in the props. React.FunctionComponent is an interface and I do not understand why I cannot use in the below code and gives me an error.

```
function Box2<React.FunctionComponent> ({ children }){
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )}
```

The error :

```
TypeError
Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/App.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (43:22)
```

Comment: `Box2<React.FunctionComponent>` is invalid usage of `FunctionComponent`. You are sending a generic parameter to `Box2` but it doesn't expect one.

Also, the following statement is not true for `react >= 18`
`we know that this generic automatically defines children in the props.`

Comment: Could you please explain it what do you mean from "You are sending a generic parameter to Box2 but it doesn't expect one."  Even if I do not use the generic inside my components it should not give me an error. For example :      function Test3<T>(){
    return (
    <h2>
     Hi
      </h2>
    )
  } is OK but 
  function Test2<React.FunctionComponent>(){
    return (
    <h2>
     Hi
      </h2>
    )
  }
is not ok

Comment: specifically `function Test2<FunctionComponent>(){ return ( <h2> Hi </h2> ) }` doesn't give an error. If it does for you, please share your tsconfig

Comment: Thank you
 TsConfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}

Comment: If you only get with `React.FunctionComponent`, then this is expected because typescript expects a generic argument name, and your name contains `.`, which causes your error

Comment: Even with your tsconfig I'm not getting an error while using `Test2<FunctionComponent>`. Are you sure that you get the error with that? Because if the `Test3` works fine for you, the same should be with this one, since you are not referencing `FunctionComponent` from `react` but rather creating a parameter with the name `FunctionComponent`

Comment: Thank you but I do not think that it is the problem.  If in the below I remove React and import React from 'react' I get another error (Cannot find name 'FunctionComponent'):
import React from 'react
const Box: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);

Comment: but why are you not importing `FunctionComponent`? How should ts find out what is it that you are using? Both of the following are valid:
`const Box: FunctionComponent = () => <h2> Hi </h2>; const Box2: React.FunctionComponent = () => <h2> Hi </h2>;`

Comment: I think I imported it wrongly. If I import it as import {FunctionComponent} from "react" then I do not have an error. But still, I did not really get why we could not use the generic of FunctionComponent inside the function component (the 2nd implementation of the Box)  rather than the variable output of the function ( the first Box example)

Comment: Passing `FunctionComponent` as a generic argument doesn't assign any type to the `Box`. It doesn't even reference the `FunctionComponent` from `react` as I mentioned in one of the previous comments. It's only a name, if you would really want to reference the `React.FunctionComponent` you would have to write something like this: `const Box = <T extends React.FunctionComponent>() => <h1>daasd</h1>;`. But even doing that you will not assign `Box` to be a functional component

Comment: So basically do you mean generic FC only use when we have a left-hand side variable that points to a function?  I generally do not get why using the same syntax in a normal function is not accepted basically

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you can't type the function declaration and it only works with function expressions. And this is not the same notation. 
The same notation for the function expressions would be the following:
`const Box = <FunctionComponent,>() => <h1>dsadas</h1>;`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think there are some stories (that I do not understand yet) there that why it only could be used for function declaration rather than function expression.